# Independence vs pairwise independence with 3 nonconform sets

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Construct the following scenario:
We have a discrete probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal P(\Omega),P)$. There are three non-empty sets $A_1,A_2$ and $A_3\subseteq\Omega$ with positive probability, where
$A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3 = \emptyset$, but $P(A_i)P(A_j)=P(A_i\cap A_j)$ $\forall i\neq j$.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  It is possible to define three events in a outcome space which are pairwise independent, but conjointly impossible.

**Hint:** Consider the outcomes for a toss of two fair coins.